# Best practice to validate JWT in Angular (detecting Token changes)

Tags: angular

I have a very basic property that checks if token is expired or not:

```
  get isExpired():boolean {
      return !!localStorage && 
             !!localStorage.getItem("token") && 
             !this.jwt.isTokenExpired(localStorage.getItem("token"));
  }
```

What is the best practice to keep watching this property in angular?

It might not be the best practice but in AngularJs I could use `$scope.$watch`

Is there any similar way to achieve the same functionality in Angular 4?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can check it only when you actually need that token, before making a request to the server. Try reducing the use of `$scope.$watch` as much as you can

Comment: My Question isn't about AngularJS. I am wondering how to do it in Angular 4 :)
I know it's expensive operator but I have to due to very sensitive component I have to redirect user to login page once the token is expired.

Answer (score 1):

I see different solutions

1. Use Guards to check your token expiration date on every change of route
   https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards
2. Create a service that checks on the token expiration every second ,

   ```
   Observable
       .interval(1000)
       .timeInterval()
       .flatMap(() => 
            this.authenticationService.isTokenExpired())
       .filter(isExpired => isExpired) 
       .subscribe(isExpired => {
           this.router.navigateByUrl("/login")
       });
   ```

this assumes that `this.authenticationService.isTokenExpired()` returns an `Observable<boolean>`